# Mutual observer

Tags: object-oriented, observer-pattern, circular-dependency

I want my **Wire** objects to be in connection with **Port** objects. That is **Port** has a list of connected wires and method `Port.add(wire)`. Similarly, Wire has list of ports it is connected to and `Wire.add(port)`.

```
class Port
  Set[Wire] connections
  method add(wire)joined)

class Wire
  Set[Port] ports
  method add(port)
```

Suppose now I use one of those methods, add a port to a wire. That method should call `port.add(this wire)` in response, to maintain coherence. But, calling `port.add(wire)` should do the same thing, it should call `wire.add(this port)` to maintain coherence. It is going to be a vicious circle. How do you break it? Do you

1. check that the object already connected and do nothing in this case or
2. make a primary connection method, forcing all users to use, say `wire.add(port)`, which will call dumb `port.wires.add(wire)` and without any further calls
3. or anything else?

Comment: How can a port be connected to multiple wires ?

Comment: @Spotted Probably. But, what if not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a port to a wire, the wire "reacts" by calling the port. This is a *different* call from an external `port.add()`, from a logical point of view.

You could have a protected method inherited from a superclass, called something like `notifyAdd`:

```
someone calls wire.add(port)
the wire initializes its own internals
the wire calls port.notifyAdd(wire)
the port initializes its own internals, but *does not* call wire.notifyAdd(port)
```

The two functions add() and notifyAdd() would be almost identical, and actually it's likely that add() would do something like calling notifyAdd() on itself and on the called object:

```
notifyAdd(wire):
    ! A wire was added to this port.
    wireCount := wireCount + 1
    ! other things
    return self

! Called externally
add(wire): public
    ! We do not trust this to make sense.
    ! We might throw WireAlreadyConnectedRecoverableException,
    ! or InvalidWireCriticalException, or ...
    sanityAssertions(self, wire)

    ! Now yes, if we're here, it made sense and we act upon it
    self.notifyAdd(wire)
    wire.notifyAdd(self)
    return self
```

Comment: Is there a relationship with [syncronosus vs async call](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) and messages that need and do not need a callback? For instance, in [Learn Some Erlang : FSMs](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/finite-state-machines#game-trading-between-two-players), we read that `negotiate({make_offer, Item}` needs to repeat the added item to the counterpart machine, whereas coutnerpart message `negotiate({do_offer, Item}`, which comes from there to us, does not send any additional messages.